# Failing using firebase-src directive inside ngFor with angularfire2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I'm new with angular, really new, and I'm trying to create a small angular app with firebase as backend.
I'm been able to retrieve a document list from Firestore and display it through a component, but what I'm trying to do now is to show an image stored into Firebase Storage, inside the ngFor that iterates the Firestore document list.
When looking into the documentation of AngularFire2, I found the firebase-src directive as a possible solution, but when I try to add it to my component template, the image isn't shown and the console shows a warning

> Can't bind to 'firebase-src' since it isn't a known property of 'img'.

I'm sure that I made something wrong and probably I'm missing something, but as I told before, I'm a completely new with Angular, like started a week ago.

So, the question is, how can I load the images from Firebase Storage into this scenario?
or maybe
Is it possible to be accomplished?

Bellow the code snippets:

pets.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";

import { PetsRoutingModule } from "./pets-routing.module";

import { PetsPageComponent } from './pets-page.component';
import {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button'
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout'

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        PetsRoutingModule,
        MatGridListModule,
        AngularFirestoreModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        AngularFireStorageModule
    ],
    declarations: [       
        PetsPageComponent,
    ]
})
export class PetsModule { }
```

pets-page.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface Pet{
  name:string;
  breed:string;
  imagepath:string;
  birthdate:object;
  gender:string;
  microchip:string;
  sterilized:boolean;
  userid:string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pets-page',
  templateUrl: './pets-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pets-page.component.scss']
})

export class PetsPageComponent implements OnInit
{
  collection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Pet>;
  petsList: Observable<Pet[]>;  

  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore, public storage: AngularFireStorage){

  }

  calculateAge(birthday) {
    var ageDifMs = Date.now() - birthday.toDate();
    const oneyear = new Date('01/01/1971');
    var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs);

    if(ageDate.getMilliseconds() < oneyear.getMilliseconds())
    {
      return (ageDate.getMonth()+1) + ' meses';
    }
    else
    {
      var yearAge = Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
      if(yearAge > 1)
      {
        return yearAge + ' anos';
      }

      return yearAge + ' ano';
    }
  }

  loadImage(pet){   
    this.storage.ref(pet.imagepath).getDownloadURL().subscribe((url) => {
      pet.imageUrl = url;
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.collection = this.firestore.collection('pets');
    this.petsList = this.collection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Pet;        
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      }))
    );
  }
}
```

pets-page.component.html

```html
<div class="row">
  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutWrap fxLayoutGap="0.5%" fxLayoutAlign="center start">
    <mat-card *ngFor="let item of petsList | async" class="m-1" id="{{item.id}}">
      <mat-card-header>
        <div mat-card-avatar class="pet-avatar-img"></div>
        <mat-card-title>
          {{item.name}}
        </mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>
          {{item.breed}}
          <br />
          {{calculateAge(item.birthdate)}}
        </mat-card-subtitle>
      </mat-card-header>      
      <img firebase-src="{{ item.imagepath }}"/>
      <mat-card-content>
        
      </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-actions class="text-right">
        <button mat-icon-button id={{item.id}}><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
        <button mat-icon-button id={{item.id}}><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
      </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found a solution, but not with angularfire directive.
I've created a pure pipe to handle the conversion of the image path stored into the Firestore document into a download url from storage.

Bellow the code of the pipe and how to use it:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';

@Pipe({
    name: 'storageurl',
    pure: true
  })

  export class StorageUrlPipe implements PipeTransform {  

    constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage){

    }

    transform(value: string, args?: any): any {
      return this.storage.ref(value).getDownloadURL();
    }

  }
```

Implementation:

```html
<img mat-card-image src="{{item.imagepath | storageurl | async}}" class="pet-image"/>
```

Pay attention to the async pipe used in the template.
It's necessary since the storageurl pipe will return an observable that needs to be resolved to retrieve the url from the storage.

I don't know if this is a clean and best practice solution, I've started with angular a week ago, but looks good for now.